# Micropython inheritance fails

Tags: micropython

I'm trying to get connect a PyBoard (I'm not sure about the hardware version, but it's running uPython 1.9.3) to a SSD1306 based LED display over I2C.

The physical connection works, and I can establish a I2C connection, see the device, and verify that it's readable on the I2C connection.

However, I'm unable to use the `ssd1306` module from the [uPython Github](https://github.com/micropython/micropython/blob/master/drivers/display/ssd1306.py).   I can import the module fine but the `SSD1306` class won't initialize.  The code which fails is this:

```
class SSD1306(framebuf.FrameBuffer):
    def __init__(self, width, height, external_vcc):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.external_vcc = external_vcc
        self.pages = self.height // 8
        self.buffer = bytearray(self.pages * self.width)
        super().__init__(self.buffer, self.width, self.height, framebuf.MONO_VLSB)
        self.init_display()
```

The error message is always

```
TypeError: function missing 1 required positional arguments
```

which seems to be spurious (i've definitely made sure to pass in the required `width`, `height`, and `external_vcc`. I'm pretty sure the problem is in the `super()` call -- but its uPython, so print-debugging inside an initializer does not seem to work.

I've read in a couple of places that uPython tends to issue bad error messages about missing params when calling a closure, but this is only vaguely similar to that.  I tried adding an explicit self to the `super().__init__()` call just in case, but that didn't work either.   So I'm a bit stuck and would welcome advice on the right next step for debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the problem is a version mismatch. At least, in the previous version of this file on the uPython github, the class does not inherit from `FrameBuffer` but instead maintains an internal one.  There's a comment in the code to this effect:

```
    # Provide methods for accessing FrameBuffer graphics primitives. This is a
    # workround because inheritance from a native class is currently unsupported.
    # http://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/pyboard/library/framebuf.html
```

So, I think the issue was a version mismatch between the 1.9.3 board and a 1.9.4 copy of the driver.  Rolling this back to the 1.9.3 code works.